# My Magento site pointing towards localhost

Tags: magento-1.8, amazon-web-services, apache

Hi I am using amazon ec2 linux instance and i have transferrd my site using to the instance using filezilla and imported the database and everything went fine.

The problem is when i try to connect to my site using my instance public ip it redirects to my localhost and  displays the site.I have changed the file permissions to 777 and the same problem exists.

If i type my public ip in browser it displays the default apache page but once if i type my public ip/magento it points towards my localhost.

Someone please guide me how to solve this issue,how do i point my public ip to display my site without redirecting to my localhost.

Sorry Iam new to linux i do know where to change my localhost and make it point towards my public ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at db table `core_config_data` and change path column `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to your live site address.

Comment: Thankyou.Worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

In core_config_data table update value of this web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url with your live domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can goto the phpmyadmin or mysql console and enter the following sql to update your base url:

```
update `core_config_data` set `value` = "your_new_unsecure_url" where `path`="web/unsecure/base_url";

update `core_config_data` set `value` = "your_new_secure_url" where `path`="web/secure/base_url";
```